# cpp pass string with variables to function

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm trying to pass a string to a function that accepts an `std::string`. But I want the string to contain three variables, a char and two integers.
I can't get it to work I currently have (example):

```
myFunction("the char is: " + std::string(&charVar) + ", int1: " + std::to_string(x1) + ", int2: " + std::to_string(x2) + " and that's it!");
```

When I print the string I get the following:

```
"the char is: U\377\377\377\377, int1: 45, int2: 6 and that's it!"
```

Where charVar = 'U', int1 = 45 and int2 = 6.

So the question is what are the /377's after U and mainly if there is a better way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: As you are new to StackOverflow (SO), please take time to read "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)". Come back and ask a question after reading [that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Additionally, be prepared to answer "[What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)"

Comment: So, what's the problem, exactly? Are you getting a compiler error?

Comment: Works for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e71491566369a3c2

Comment: Oops had the problem ready but forgot to paste it! Sorry editing my post now!

Comment: @JaapWijnen You cannot pass a pointer to a character to the constructor of `std::string` and expect just one character in the resulting `std::string` instance. This constructor expects C-style strings to be terminated by `null` characters when a pointer to a `char` is passed to it. The constructor will start reading characters starting from that pointer until it finds a `null` character. Your program will probably produce different results every time you run it.

Comment: Yes it does! Do you know an alternative?

Comment: I would suggest using a [std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to construct the string to be passed to your function like @PaulMcKenzie suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::ostringstream`

```
#include <sstream>
//...
std::ostringstream strm;
strm << "the char is: " << charVar << ", int1: " << 
     x1 << ", int2: " << x2 <<  " and that's it!";
myFunction(strm.str());
```